# Validation Rule Formula where 3 $amount fields must = a 4th $amount field

Tags: formula

I have a total of 4 fields where 3 of them must equal the 4th value. So...

$amount of 'Write-off'
+ $amount of 'Goodwill'
+ $amount of 'Customer'
must equal what is shown in 'Exposure'

The rule should fire if the first 3 fields are not equal to the amount shown in the 'Exposure' field.

Any help in writing this formula is appreciated.

Comment: If you are new to writing formulas, you should definitely complete the [Formulas and Validations module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/point_click_business_logic) at Salesforce Trailhead, and also take a look at the Advanced Formulas module.

Answer (score 2):

```
{writeoff} + {goodwill} + {customer} <> {exposure}
```

For a validation to fire, the formula must return TRUE .

Comment: Thanks, Brian...that did the trick! I will definitely review the Trailheads as recommended also. Very much appreciate your help! :-)